# Is the interval for the middle point of the Mean Value Theorem open or closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me understand some math that my teacher wrote.

He defined the (Lagrange) MVT as:

> If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then $\exists c\in(a,b)$ such that:
> $f(b) - f(a) = f'(c)(b-a)$.

This makes sense. But then he said that, in fact, one could write $c\in[a,b]$ instead.

He then let $c = a$ and wrote $f'(c)$. I think this is wrong because $f(x)$ might not be differentiable at $a$.

He told me to consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

Am I missing something, or did he make a mistake?

Edit: More context. This was a question on an exam and I got it correct (other than leaving out $f\in C[a,b]$), but when he went over the solutions in class, he said the $c\in(a,b)$ could be $c\in[a,b]$.

[image: Use MVT to prove e^x >= 1 + x]

Comment: I think that your professor was making a statement which follows from, but is not equivalent to the MVT. $\exists c\in(a,b)$ implies $\exists c\in[a,b]$, but not necessarily the other way around. If $c=a$ or $c=b$, then there should still be more point(s) in $(a,b)$ which satisfy the MVT though, but if he's just looking for one on $[a,b]$, the $c=a$ suffices.

Comment: If there is a $c\in (a,b)$ with a property then it is true there is a $c\in[a,b]$ with that property, most obviously the same $c$.  But since $f$ is not guaranteed to be differentiable at $a$ or $b$ it probably does not help to widen in this way, even if it is not wrong.

Comment: In any case, the statement of the theorem requires $a < b$.  Otherwise consider your $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $a=b=0$

Comment: And the $c$ is not free to be taken $=a$. The allowed values of $c$ depends on $a$, $b$ and $f$ and not always those values include $a$.

Comment: I want to make sure we're using the same notation. $()$ means open interval. $[]$ means closed interval. $(a,b) = [a,b] \setminus\{a,b\}$. @Angelica

Comment: @AdamNeeley Yes, that is the notation convention that I used.

Comment: I updated the question with some more context. @Henry

Comment: With the added context, the inequality boxed has nothing to do with the mean value theorem, but rather the increasing quality of $e^x$. Since $c>0$, it must be that $e^c\geq e^0=1$. As it happens, strict inequality also follows ($e^c>e^0$), but that is not what you(r professor?) are trying to prove.

Comment: Responding to the context: I do not see any statement of $c \in [a,b]$ here. You highlighted the inequality in part (b); your teacher is saying that $e^c x \geq e^0 x$ when $c > 0$ and $x > 0$, which he uses to show $e^x - 1 \geq x$.

Comment: It's easy to miss, but I worded it carefully: "But then he said that, in fact, one could write $c\in[a,b]$ instead." @NickSweeney

Comment: I do see that the writing on part (a) looks like it says $c \in [a,b]$ at a glance. Rather, I believe $C[a,b]$ denotes the set of functions continuous on $[a,b]$, and $C(a,b)$ denotes the set of functions continuous on $(a,b)$.

Comment: But $c>0$, so how could $e^cx = e^0x$? It should be $>$, not $\ge$, or am I misunderstanding the meaning of $\ge$? @Angelica

Comment: $v\geq w$ means $v>w$ OR $v=w$. This means that if $v>w$ is true, then $v\geq w$ must also be true. In logical symbolism, $(v>w)\rightarrow(v\geq w)$. For $v\geq w$ to be true, it does not need to also be the case that $v=w$, which as you noted is false

Comment: @AdamNeeley If your teacher said "in fact one could write $c \in [a,b]$" to you in person, then I'm not sure what your teacher means. Concerning the highlighted inequality, the derivative $e^x$ is strictly increasing in $x$, so if we were to say $c = 0$, the Mean Value Theorem means we must have $x = e^c x \leq f(x)-f(0) = e^x - 1$. We are still using the existence of another $c \in (a,b)$ for which $x-0 = f'(c) (f(x)-f(x))$ to obtain this inequality though

Comment: @AdamNeeley You should be aware that $\geq$ means greater than or equal to. I.e., $e^c x \geq e^0 x$ means $e^c x > e^0 x$ or $e^c x = e^0 x$. Why would $e^c x \geq e^0 x$ mean $e^c x = e^0 x$? We already have a symbol that means this, and that symbol is $=$. It's a surprise to me that this is a source of confusion, since inequalities are taught in grade school well before calculus and real analysis.

Comment: %@#&. Thank you. I still don't understand why he said $c\in [a,b]$. I think that threw me off. @Angelica

Comment: It's not the source of confusion. I just got so confused after he said $c\in[a,b]$ that I didn't even consider that inequality could be true for other reasons. And yeah, I made stupid mistake in the process. Thank you to @Angelica for identifying it. I will mention to my teacher that it's right, but not for the reason he said. Edit: actually I will insist that $c\notin[a,b]$, because that's really the important part. I shouldn't have highlighted the inequality. Sorry.

Comment: I removed the misleading highlight. If anyone has any idea why $c$ could be in $[a,b]$, please let me know. In theory, the previous comments should still apply (like $c\in(a,b) \implies c\in[a,b]$), but I don't understand why they would be true, unless maybe $a=b$, in which case I don't understand the relevance. Thanks.

Comment: @AdamNeeley Okay great!

Comment: There's no need to be rude and passive aggressive. Have a nice day @NickSweeney

Comment: My bad. I was just intrigued to think you were studying analysis without knowing inequalities, but I realize how I came across, and I'm sorry. The "Okay great!" was sincere. I wanted to end with something nice after you cleared up what you meant. @AdamNeeley

Comment: Well, that's a nice gesture, but my question is still unresolved. I downloaded the zoom meeting and yep, he says $c\in[a,b]$. The strange thing is that this is from an exam, and I got actually got this question right (including the $\ge$), but I just lost it when he said $c\in[a,b]$. There's no way.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131894/discussion-on-question-by-adam-neeley-is-the-interval-for-the-middle-point-of-th).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is upon the proof of the Mean Value Theorem, and that proof rely on Rolle's Theorem, in wich necessarily $c\in (a,b)$, otherwise the MVT does not take place.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but I figured out why he said $c\in[a,b]$. It was because if $f(x)=e^x$, then $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f'(x)$ is increasing $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ (and $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$). Normal people would just say $e^c \ge e^0$ because in this case $c>0$.

Answer (score 2):

The Mean Value Theorem states $c \in (a,b)$, i.e. the interval is open. I'm not sure why your teacher would state it with $c \in [a,b]$, as $c \in (a,b)$ is a stronger result. And you're right that $c \in \{a,b\}$ doesn't make sense when differentiability at $a,b$ is not specified. There are of course examples where $f'(a) = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, e.g. if $f$ is the constant function $f=0$ and $[a,b]$ is some interval, then $f'(a) = 0 = \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. The Mean Value Theorem dictates that some $c \in (a,b)$ must satisfy this too though.

I definitely don't get your teacher's example of $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. The derivative of this function is strictly decreasing, so anytime $[a,b]$ is an interval on the domain, $c \in (a,b)$ has $f'(b)(b-a) < f'(c)(b-a) < f'(a)(b-a)$, so not only do we not need to consider the endpoints $a,b$, but the endpoints never work.

EDIT: The commenter @Henry is right that if $a = b$ and if $f$ is differentiable at this point, then we always have $f(b) - f(a) = f'(a) (b-a) = 0$. One could define $[a,a] = \{a\}$, so $a \in [a,a]$ as needed. Meanwhile, one could define $(a,a) = \varnothing$, so there is no $c \in (a,a)$ to consider in this case. Maybe this is what your teacher means, although I'm not sure what the point is of considering this. The Mean Value Theorem generally has the condition $a < b$.

Answer (score 2):

With your edited question,

- your typed statement of the MVT starts *"If $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and ..."*
- while your handwritten answer starts *"Let $f \in C^1(a,b) \implies \cdots$"*

Your teacher corrected this to $[a,b]$, as you need continuity at $a$ and $b$ for the theorem to apply

Comment: Yeah, I wrote that in the edit. But doesn’t differentiability over (a,b)  imply continuity over [a, b]?

Comment: @AdamNeeley No: for example if $f(x)=x$ for $x \in (0,1)$ while $f(0)=3$ and $f(1)=2$ then $f$ is differentiable over $(0,1)$ with $f'(x)=1$ but the mean value theorem does not apply

Comment: Ahh, very nice. Thank you.